# Cannot run ctags after executing "ln -s /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant"

Tags: bash, ctags, exuberant-ctags, ln

By mistake I have executed the following command on my redhat office machine and now I cannot run `ctags -R *` any more.

`ln -s /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`

Hope following info helps,
`[ypp:~]$ ls /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`
`[ypp:~]$ ls: /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant: No such file or directory`

`[ypp:~]$ unlink /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`
`unlink: cannot unlink /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant': No such file or directory`

`[ypp:~]$ which ctags`
`alias ctags='/usr/bin/ctags'`
`/usr/bin/ctags`

`[ypp:~]$ ln -s /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant /usr/bin/ctags`
`ln: creating symbolic link '/usr/bin/ctags' to '/usr/bin/ctags-exuberant': File exists`

`[ypp:~]$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/ctags /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`
`ln: creating symbolic link ,/usr/bin/ctags-exuberant' to '/usr/local/bin/ctags': Permission denied`

So far I have tried,

`[ypp:~]$ rm /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`
`/bin/rm: cannot lstat /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant': No such file or directory`

`[ypp:~]$ rm -i /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`
`/bin/rm: cannot lstat /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant': No such file or directory`

`[ypp:~]$ unlink /usr/bin/ctags`
`unlink: cannot unlink /usr/bin/ctags': Permission denied`

Please tell me how do I get my ctags working back to normal,
I don't have superuser privilege also.

Comment: From where did you execute `ln -s /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln), `ln` creates a link to file `TARGET` with the name `LINKNAME`. If `LINKNAME` is omitted, as was your case, a link to `TARGET` is created in the **current directory**, using the name of `TARGET` as the `LINKNAME`. As a result, when you executed `ln -s /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant` a symbolic link (sometimes called soft link) named `ctags-exuberant` would have been created in your present working directory pointed at `/usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`.

---

There seems to be more at play than what you have shared with us here. Simply creating a link to `ctags-exuberant` in any directory should not have resulted in the changes you are experiencing. Where there other changes made to your `path`?

If, somehow just creating the link has caused all your troubles, then you need to focus on finding the resulting link and removing it. If you don't know what directory it was created in, you could find it via the following:

```
find / -type l -name 'ctags-exuberant' 2>/dev/null
```

Once it is found, remove it and see if that fixes your problems. Let us know what you find.

Else, you might do better to try the wise minds over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/